# Listing one array next to another in one message

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I have two arrays and I want to list in one entry of Array 1 next to an entry from Array 2.

My two Arrays are named `memberIDs` and `rolesIDs`. Whereas `memberIDs` contains the IDs from member in a voice Channel, `roleIDs` lists a ton of IDs from different roles.
To list them next to each other I made the following code:

```
message.channel.send(memberIDs.map(element => "<@" + element + "> -> " + rolesIG.map(element => "<@&" + element + ">" ).join()).join("\n"));
```

Sadly it isn't working like I want it to, although it lists all member seperatly, on the other site it lists **all** entrys from `roleIDs` like this:

> <@memberID1> -> <@&roleID1> <@&roleID2> <@&roleID3>

> <@memberID2> -> <@&roleID1> <@&roleID2> <@&roleID3>

It want it to behave like this:

> <@memberID1> -> <@roleID1>

> <@memberID2> -> <@roleID2>

I apprectiate any help.

Comment: it's not clear how the rolesIDs structure is made and how it handles the coupling between roles and users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var outarr = []
for(var i = 0; i < memberIDs.length; i++) {
  outarr[i] = `<@${memberIDs[i]}> -> <@${rolesIG[i]}>`
}
```

now `outarr` is a list, where each item contains the member ID concatenated with the roleIG